# TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException: Missing [assembly:GeneratorPlugin] attribute

Tags: specflow

I'm just now learning about SpecFlow.  I'm trying to work through the BookShop example [here](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Getting-Started/Getting-Started-With-An-Example.html) and my attempt to Run All Tests reveals a build error:

```
Error   MSB4018 The "GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task failed unexpectedly.
TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException: Missing [assembly:GeneratorPlugin] attribute in 
C:\Users\john.robottom\.nuget\packages\specrun.specflow.3-40\3.4.5\build\\net471\SpecRun.Generator.SpecFlowPlugin.dll
```

I've googled around, but I'm unclear if I need to downgrade something (if so, what and how to downgrade), un-install and re-install (what), etc.

Comment: Which version of the SpecFlow plugin do you have installed? Which version of the SpecFlow NuGet package do you have installed? Are you using Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? Are you running tests from the command line, and if so, how? We need more information to help  you. Ideally, we need a [repro].

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how to reply to Greg's questions via a comment (it says I can't comment until I have 50 points).  So, here is my attempt to answer to Greg's questions (if you need other info, Greg, just let me know):

1. SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDocPlugin:  3.4.2
2. SpecRun.Runner:  3.3.41
3. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise
4. I'm running tests from Test Explorer in Viual Studio.

Basically, I followed the example and took the latest stable (as of a few days ago) NuGet package for any packages referenced in the example.
The example is at:  https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Getting-Started/Getting-Started-With-An-Example.html

Comment: I updated all NuGet packages of the bookshop example to the latest version, but I could not reproduce your issue. Could you check it again?